# JavaScript Smooth Animation with a game loop

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, game-physics

I've simplified my game loop to just a box moving across the screen, [Click Here](http://test.mrslayer.com).  For some reason, the box doesn't seem to move smoothly.  I've made a [video of it here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGaf6622Ax8&feature=plcp).

The game loop is called like so:

```
var game = function( ) {
    var now = Date.now( );
    var delta = now - then;

    update( delta / 1000 );
    draw( );

    then = now;
};

setInterval( game, 1000 / 50 );
```

I have tried separating the `draw` calls from the main game loop and put them in `requestAnimationFrame`, but the problem persists.  I've looked at a bunch of tutorials that seem to run smoothly.  I've even tried using a [fixed time-step game loop](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html), but that just made my game run unmanageably fast.

How can I improve upon the above logic, perhaps utilizing the `requestAnimationFrame` and maintaining `deltaTime` for the `update` calls.

Comment: I didn't see that at all, it also said `59` all the time. Is that the fps?

Comment: Hmmm, yes 59 is my attempt at displaying the number of updates per second.  On my Mac in both Safari and Chrome, I am seeing the paddles and ball jump forward a little bit, instead of moving smoothly.  I guess I should check it on some other computers.

Comment: I guess the ball is a bit jerky if I look really closely... this is because in some frames, the ball moves more than 1px at a time.

Comment: Correct.  Is there a way to correct this behavior?  I thought that by having my updates based on `deltaTime` (time diff. between update cycles) that would smooth things out.

Comment: I don't seem to notice that behavior on my computer, but that is most likely because the FPS more or less constant. However, this is most likely a biproduct of the fact that you are drawing too much, make a separate canvas that you don't update that has the background on it or make yourself a system that only draws dirty items (stuff that has changed position/scale/rotation/color etc)

Comment: Fix your timestep! http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe when using canvas your position variables should be integer values because they represent pixels and floating point values do not make sense. If you open up the console and enter in `sceneManager.currentScene.GameplayLayer.ball.position.x` then you get back a really long decimal. I think the comment on the OP that suggests that sometimes the ball is moving 2px instead of a 1px may be on to something. When you update your position you end up with a floating point value.

I believe it sometimes rounds up to the next highest pixel position, sometimes down. I would try taking the floor or ceiling like so:

```
this.position.x += Math.floor(this.speed * 100 * deltaTime * Math.cos(directionInRadians));
this.position.y += Math.floor(this.speed * 100 * deltaTime * Math.sin(directionInRadians));
```

I would make both of these changes and see how it behaves.

EDIT: Since you edited your question to simplify the logic. I can suggest something to try, which is to use this Clock object I created which I use all the time. It gives me smooth animation and it's rather simple. It is based off of the [clock that Three.JS uses](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Clock.js) so you might want to check that out as well. Even if you want to use your own code you can at least try this ready-made solution and see if it gives you the same results. It seems to work just fine for me. Also, you tried using the shim so your call in the game function should be `requestAnimFrame(game);`?

```
var Clock = function () {

    /** Member startTime will remain fixed at its integer
        millisecond value returned by Date.now(). Will always
        be equal to the time the clock was started */
    this.startTime = Date.now();

    /** Member ms is updated by tick() to a integer value reprsenting 
        the number of milliseconds between the epoch (January 1, 1970)
        and the current date and time of the system. */
    this.ms = this.startTime;
    this.last = this.startTime;  /** millis at last call to tick() */
    this.time = 0;               /** ms in floating point seconds not millis */

    /** Member dt is updated by tick() to an integer value representing
        the number of milliseconds since the last call to tick(). */
    this.dt = 0;
    this.delta = 0; /** dt in floating point seconds not millis */

    /** Member fps is updated by tick() to a floating point value representing
        frames per second, updated and averaged approximately once per second */
    this.fps = 0.0;

    /** Member frameCount is updated to an integer value representing the
        total number of calls to tick() since the clock was created. */
    this.frameCount = 0;

    /** The frameCounter member is a flag you can turn off if you don't need to
        calculate the frameCount or do the average FPS calculation every second */
    this.frameCounter = true;

    /** Private globals needed to calculcate/average fps over eachs second */
    var timeToUpdate = 0;
    var framesToUpdate = 0;

    /************************************************************************************
        The tick() method updates ALL the Clock members, which should only
        be read from and never written to manually. It is recommended that
        tick() is called from a callback loop using requestAnimationFrame

        Learn more: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
    *************************************************************************************/
    this.tick = function () {
        /** This is a new frame with it's very own unique number */

        if (this.frameCounter) this.frameCount++;

        /** Set the private currentTime variable */
        this.ms = Date.now();

        /** Update time delta and immediately set last time to
            be as accurate as possible in our timings. */
        this.dt = this.ms - this.last;
        this.last = this.ms;

        /** Calculate floating-point delta and increment time member */
        this.delta = 0.001 * this.dt;
        this.time += this.delta;

        /** Calculate private temp variables for fps calculation */
        if (this.frameCounter) {
            timeToUpdate += this.dt;
            framesToUpdate++;
            if (timeToUpdate > 1000) {
                this.fps = Math.round((framesToUpdate * 1000) / timeToUpdate);
                framesToUpdate = 0;
                timeToUpdate = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you use this object then all you need to do is create a new clock object in your initialization function like so `clock = new Clock();`. Then call `clock.tick()` in each animation call. You can then access the members `clock.delta` and `clock.time` which will give you the delta and time as a floating point value in seconds. `clock.dt` and `clock.ms` will give you the same as integer in millseconds. You can also access the fps using `clock.fps` or disable it by setting `clock.frameCounter = false`.

Comment: Well I tried your suggestion, and it still presented the same problems.  I think my game loop logic is just not right for some reason, and everything I try seems to react the same way.  I took someone else's code and was able to make a smooth animation on my computer, so I may have to rework my game into their main loop and see what happens.  Thanks again for the help.  I wish there was an be-all-end-all game loop logic for JavaScript.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, you're structuring in this application is carried out well, but it seems really complex for what you have so far. I would start out with 3 functions init, animate, and render. Get it working well in the simplest terms possible and build up your abstractions as you add complexity to your game. All the different files and classes seems a bit overkill for what you have so far. It does look like good programming to me though. Some little thing is probably just not right, and its hard to visualize program flow as simple as it is.

Comment: Heads up: I've simplified the logic and updated my question.  This answer may no longer be pertinent.

Comment: Thanks for the continued interest.  I built a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MR7G3/) that utilizes the Clock class.  I must be crazy, because I still see a choppy animation at 60 FPS.  I dropped it to 30 FPS and it reacts the same.  I think my expectations might be too high for JavaScript and I may have to just settle.  The box moves at the correct speed, but it kind of stutters every now and again.  I turned on the FPS counter in about:flags in Chrome, and it shows valleys whenever the animation jerks.

Comment: Hm, it seems to run pretty smooth for me... I think what you are referring to and seeing is caused by the garbage collector clearing things up every so often.. May I inqure as to what browser you are running and perhaps any extensions that might effect things? Or does it do the exact same in all? For me it definitely is the smoothest in Chrome, but before you give up on Javascript all together, you might want to check out the Three.JS examples and see how the Canvas demos run on your machine using that library. It has an excellent canvas renderer that is also silky smooth for me.

Comment: Try looking at the [animation in this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic.html) and see if it is choppy. That example is done with Three.JS using canvas. It rotates 100% perfectly smooth on just about any machine I've run this on using Chrome. If the Three.JS examples work well for you I might would recommend using their library with canvas renderer. In my opinion it is much better than using the canvas api alone.

Answer (score 1):

Using `three.js` clock smoothed up my animation. I highly recommend it. Tons of other good code in there as well.

Comment: `clock.js` use `Date.now()` for its implementation. i'm a wondering how it could be smoother than code in the OP.

Comment: @tigrou `Date.now` is used because, despite the naming, it is more performant than `performance.now`. They are both very fast these days, but since it is called every single frame, you want something as fast as possible. The advantage of `performance.now` over `Date.now` (and any other method of obtaining timestamps in JavaScript) is that `performance.now` has sub-millisecond precision. In the case of animation, the one millisecond precision of `Date.now` is plenty. Usage of `performance.now` would be more appropriate in applications like benchmarking, physics simulation, etc.